# Build pie chart with sectors d3js

Tags: d3.js

I want to build this kind of chart with d3js (no need in any North, East etc.)
just this kind of data

[{year:2017, data:[10,20,30]}, {year:2016, data:[20,20,30]}]
Is there any example pie with sectors?
Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think what might be similar to what you want is:

[Sequential Sunburst Diagrams](https://bl.ocks.org/kerryrodden/7090426)

In the main gallery for [d3js](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Gallery) you can find some examples for **sunburst** graphs

Answer (score 0):

D3 has a method for generating arc segments of varying widths specified by inner and outer radius, start and end angles [d3.arc](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#arcs)

```
var arc = d3.arc();

arc({
  innerRadius: 0,
  outerRadius: 100,
  startAngle: 0,
  endAngle: Math.PI / 2
});
```

in order to create the kind of diagram you have in mind you'll need to work out what those properties are for each piece of data you have. This is typically achieved using a layout function; you pass an array of your data to the function and it returns an array of values required to create the arc segments.

The process by which you convert the data values to arc properties is where the difficult work lies. I've created [a bl.ock giving an example of how you might do this](https://bl.ocks.org/tomgp/bead4692d3903ea057780b9d2fdfb164) though if you're using this layout you should make sure that the areas rather than arc thickness are proportional to the data values for expedience I haven't.